# Running access macro with python

Tags: python, win32com, taskmanager

Using python 3.9 Here is my python code:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

strDbName = 'S:\Public\Maintenance\MaintPMprototypev1_4.accdb'
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('autoexport')
objAccess.Application.CloseCurrentDatabase()
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

Honestly, it worked this morning but then I was trying to run it with Task Scheduler and made a batch file for Task Scheduler to run and now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\charlie.zigler\Desktop\autoexport.py", line 10, in <module>
    objAccess.Visible = False
  File "C:\Users\charlie.zigler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 592, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Visible.', 'dao360.chm', 2015567, -2146825833), None)
```

I had it backed up, so I deleted the batch file I created and deleted the py file and copy and pasted the backup py file and tried and still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run the macro outside of python? Does the part of the error that says _'You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Visible.'_ give a clue? It's possibly an error from Access, not from python

Comment: After a restart it works again but does anyone have any suggestions on how to get Task Scheduler to run it?

Comment: _After a restart..._, do you mean it just runs once using Task Manager ?

Comment: I mean I restarted the computer and now when I run the script it works fine again. It opens access, runs the macro and closes like it is supposed to. So somehow when I made the batch file to run the py script and told Task Scheduler to run it, it broke something that restarting windows fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got everything to work now, so after restarting windows it allowed the script to work again and then I created a new batch file with just the script location and it runs just fine.